# Background Ripple Effect on StandAlone Toolbar items is gone

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Using the Standalone toolbar has an issue with the select able background of the items, following this article didn't work also:

http://blog.mohitkanwal.com/blog/2015/03/07/styling-material-toolbar-in-android/

Check the normal toolbar in the below screenshot, the ripple effect selector is gone when using the standalone toolbar.

here is my style:

```
 <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/green</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowToggle</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MoreActionButton</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accentColor</item>
    </style>
```

**EDIT:**
After isolating the issue from my code I was able to reproduce the issue and it seems it is related to the new support design library. And here is the test code that has the issue:

[TestToolbar.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0J-pFNkRpd8MU1RaG1ucE1EYVU/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? you are not getting the selectors?

Comment: I don't get the selectors of the Toolbar items, that green ripple effect behind he search item on the above picture, it is gone when I use standalone toolbar instead of a normal toolbar.

Comment: It might be an issue, so I filed a bug for the library: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176431

Comment: @MahdiHijazi thanks for the bug filled. I do not agree with the Google team that it "works as intended" because if it did we wouldn't be needing workarounds. But the transparent background worked fine.

Answer (score 25):

This was done using android 5.1 genymotion emulator

I didn't figure out your problem, but I just tried to create a toolbar the same as yours, but with removing some style that I don't have

here is my style

```
  <style name="ToolbarTheme"
      parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#1bff3a</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFF</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accentColor</item>
  </style>
```

---

My Toolbar layout

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?colorPrimary"
      app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      />
```

---

My Menu

```
<item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"
      app:showAsAction="always"
      />
```

---

The activity code

```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_home);
```

---

Screenshot of the result

[image: Screenshot of working toolbar]

---

**Edit**

after downloading the sample you provided in the question, the problem has nothing to do with standalone toolbar or actionbar (both have the same problem) when using `AppBarLayout`, the problem seems that the `Ripple` effect will be drawn on `AppBarLayout` instead of the View of the selected menu item, I'll record a video explaining it.

the video:
[AppBarLayout with Toolbar Video](https://youtu.be/0F9TeiYzBh4)

I'll try to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the ripple effect is still there but the ripple color has changed. I am not sure of what your problem is but this is what I see.

I suggest you remove

```
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accentColor</item>
```

from your code and run it again. If the ripples dont display (they should), change the accent color.

Answer (score 6):

The workaround regarding the `selectableItemBackground` also didn't work for me. The best strategy I came up till now is to set the background of the Toolbar to transparent:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   ...
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

This enables the ripple effect (cropped to the Actionbar heigth) in expanded/collapsed/intermediate state.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

Define a custom theme in the styles.xml

```
<style name="MyAppbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this theme on the AppBarLayout or Toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppbarTheme" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Chris Bane answer on the original issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176431

This is because by default ?attr/actionBarItemBackground is an unbounded RippleDrawable, which means that it projects/draws onto the next parent. In this case, this is the CollapsingToolbarLayout which you can't actually see.

There's not much we can do here from a library perspective. The 'workaround' is to set actionBarItemBackground to not be borderless:

```
<style name="Theme.Toolbar.Collapsing" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>

<Toolbar
    ...
    android:theme="Theme.Toolbar.Collapsing" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Good example from my project:

```
            android:id="@+id/..."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."
            android:background="@drawable/button_ripple_circle_green"
            android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:elementColor="@color/white"
            app:hintColor="@color/text_disabled_light"
            app:leftIconMode="back"
            app:leftSearchSpace="@dimen/..."
            app:textColor="@color/white"
            app:textSize="@dimen/..."
            tools:visibility="visible" />
```

This is xml (android:background) where is  ripple effect on icons "search" & "back":

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/icon_toolbar_pressed"/>
        <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/primary"/>
        <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```