# Design Support Library, Toolbar buttons cropped ripple

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to utilize the `CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout, CollapsingToolbarLayout, Toolbar` and a parallax'ed `ImageView`. It looks like the ripple effect of the toolbar menu items is cropped. The following image displays the ripple effect of the back button in expanded and in partially collapsed mode. In complete collapsed mode the ripple effect is not shown at all. I think this is caused by the parallax'ed `ImageView` that is positioned there.

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="224dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.4"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `ImageView` displays a `9-patch`'ed Image. Is there something wrong with the layout or is it a bug/inability in the design support library to draw the ripple ontop of the ImageView?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576926/background-ripple-effect-on-standalone-toolbar-items-is-gone
Workaround is discussed here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&start=0&num=100&q=CollapsingToolbarLayout%20Ripple&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=176431

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your solution is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176431).

You can try to add this line:

```
<item name="actionBarItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
```

in the theme/style of your Toolbar.

If it doesn't work, add this in your `Toolbar` attributes:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: This is exactly the link I provided when I marked this question as a duplicate. Back then I also proposed the workaround with the transparent background, both in the android bug tracker and in the referenced SO question.

However I'm willing to accept *your* answer if you think this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your own comment when I encountered this issue… Anyway, I didn't found the question link you provided in your comment when I searched on Google for my issue, and your one is better explained with visuals, so I think it's not really a duplicate and this thread could help future programmers to quickly get the solution