# How to set Toolbars NavIcon ripple color programmatically?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, rippledrawable

The color of an Activity needs to become changed during runtime. Setting the color of the ToolBar and StatusBar, text colors, etc. programmatically works fine.

Also altering the color of the NavIcon works fine.

```
    final Drawable immutableNavIcon = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
    if (immutableNavIcon != null) {
        Drawable navIcon = immutableNavIcon.mutate();
        navIcon.setColorFilter(foregroundColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(navIcon);
    }
```

**How to change also the ripple color of the NavIcon?**

Answer (score 0):

Use this theme in your toolbar..

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme"
  parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">#1bff3a</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#FFF</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFF</item>
<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accentColor</item>
```

see here [background ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676995/2959200)

Comment: I need to do it during runtime, so setting a new theme doesn't work