# How to remove the shadow of icons in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to remove the shadow in ActionBar ?

For Example :

[image]

When I touch my icon,the shadow appear,so how to remove it?

[ADD] It's different from ToolBar,when I use ToolBar Theme,I got a resource not found error.

[ADD] This app is running at Android 4.4

Comment: That looks like a normal behavior which is coming from Android itself. Not sure if we can make it disappear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background Ripple Effect on StandAlone Toolbar items is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576926/background-ripple-effect-on-standalone-toolbar-items-is-gone)

Comment: ToolBar is different form ActionBar,I think the AppCompat theme is unuseful for ActionBar.

Comment: [Notice]:This app is running at Android 4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is useful.I set

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@color/actionbar_button_background</item>
```

Which the 'actionbar_button_background' is same of the ActionBar background Color.